# Changing font family of all Material UI components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Can we change the font family of Material UI components with less code? I have tried many ways but still, I can't able to do it. I have to change the font family
individually which is really a lot of work. Are there any other ways to do that?

Comment: Do we have any solution for same problem in version 0 of material UI?

Comment: https://material-ui.com/customization/typography

Answer (score 143, accepted):

You can change the font in material-ui@next library doing the following. Suppose in your `<App />` which is defined like the following

```
// Material UI
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from 'material-ui/styles';

const App = () => (
  <MuiThemeProvider theme={THEME}>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={appHistory} routes={Routes} />
    </Provider>
  </MuiThemeProvider>
 );

 ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

In the `theme` prop for `MuiThemeProvider` you provide the following where

```
const THEME = createMuiTheme({
   typography: {
    "fontFamily": `"Roboto", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif`,
    "fontSize": 14,
    "fontWeightLight": 300,
    "fontWeightRegular": 400,
    "fontWeightMedium": 500
   }
});
```

Then somewhere in your `css` or your main `index.html` file include this `@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700');`

For a list of all params you can give to `createMuiTheme` [Default Theme Params](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/themes/) Regarding the docs itself for changing the MuiTheme they are as follows. [Themes Material UI Next](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/themes/)

Regarding the `<Reboot />` part you can have a look at the documentation here [Material UI Reboot Details](https://material-ui-next.com/style/reboot/)

Comment: It Works.. But if we include any div component we need to change font styles,right?

Comment: That depends, The general font which being applied to entire Material UI components can be set like the way I have mentioned above. But if you want custom fonts for every different `div` tag then you need to specify it separately.

Comment: Ok. As mentioned above I can be able to change the font family. But there is another problem. I want to change the background colour and colour of the Typography fonts on selecting the texts of the typography. Can we able to do that using Muithemeprovider?

Comment: You can change the color of the font, but not the background-color. Have a look at https://material-ui-next.com/customization/theme-default/ If you want to change the background-color you will have to over-ride that component.

Comment: it works for me,but i got this warning : Material-UI: you are using the deprecated typography variants that will be removed in the next major release

Comment: @Reza Material-UI is deprecating the old typography API, so it gives a warning message. In order to use the latest typography. Add this in the `typography` object.

```typography: { useNextVariants: true } ```

Comment: (!) This answer should be updated for new v5+.

Answer (score 54):

**** **UPDATES** *****

Adding to the accepted answer by Adeel.

For the latest Material-UI(v4+) components, the imports, as well as `MuiThemeProvider`, have been changed.

So now in your `App.js`, do the following:

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/styles';
import './Styles/App.css';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily: [
      'Nunito',
      'Roboto',
      '"Helvetica Neue"',
      'Arial',
      'sans-serif'
    ].join(','),
  }
});

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <div className="App">
          <MainApp />
        </div>
      </ThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Now for example, I've added the **`Nunito`** font. So I had to add the same to the `App.css` (which is being imported in `App.js`) in the following way:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Nunito';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Nunito Regular'), local('Nunito-Regular'), 
   url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/nunito/v11/XRXV3I6Li01BKofINeaBTMnFcQ.woff2) 
   format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, 
    U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, 
    U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
```

Comment: How can we add multiple fonts? For example, Nunito and Montserrat

Answer (score 32):

In MUI v5, also make sure ThemeProvider and createTheme is imported from `@mui/material/styles` and not from `@mui/styles`. I was stuck for hours thinking why it's not working.

```
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/styles'; ❌

import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles'; ✅

const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    allVariants: {
      fontFamily: 'serif',
      textTransform: 'none',
      fontSize: 16,
    },
  },
});

function App() {
  return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        ...
      </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why MUI Team didn't issue a warning in this case?

Answer (score 11):

In **MUI v5**, you can update the `fontFamily` or any other CSS properties of all `Typography` variants easily:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    allVariants: {
      fontFamily: 'serif',
    },
  },
})
```

To change the `fontFamily` dynamically in your app, you can use `useMemo` to create a new `theme` object based on the latest `fontFamily` value:

```
const defaultFontFamily = 'serif';
const [fontFamily, setFontFamily] = React.useState(defaultFontFamily);

const theme = React.useMemo(
  () =>
    createTheme({
      typography: {
        allVariants: { fontFamily },
      },
    }),
  [fontFamily],
);

return (
  <div>
    <Select
      defaultValue={defaultFontFamily}
      onChange={(e) => setFontFamily(e.target.value)}
    >
      <MenuItem value="serif">serif</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value="sans-serif">sans-serif</MenuItem>
    </Select>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Content />
    </ThemeProvider>
  </div>
);
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 6):

Hoping this can help someone...you need to be really careful with commas and brackets when declaring your styles within `createMuiTheme`

It's really easy to mess this up. For instance, palette is one big object...so is typography, make sure everything is in the right place. I had random problems caused by doing this wrong.

```
  palette: {
    primary: {
      light: '#ff8e8c',
      main: '#ff5a5f',
      dark: '#c62035',
      contrastText: '#fff',
    },
    secondary: {
      light: '#4da9b7',
      main: '#017a87',
      dark: '#004e5a',
      contrastText: '#000',
    },
  },
  typography: {
    allVariants: {
      fontFamily: "'Montserrat', sans-serif",
      textTransform: "none",
    }
    button: {
      textTransform: "none",
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 4):

This is now the preferred method:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily: [
      '-apple-system',
      'BlinkMacSystemFont',
      '"Segoe UI"',
      'Roboto',
      '"Helvetica Neue"',
      'Arial',
      'sans-serif',
      '"Apple Color Emoji"',
      '"Segoe UI Emoji"',
      '"Segoe UI Symbol"',
    ].join(','),
  },
});
```

As noted here:
https://material-ui.com/customization/typography/

Comment: This isn't working for me when I'm trying to import a local .ttf file. I'm using webpack and importing it in the file of the component where I'm making my theme with createMuiTheme and including in my ThemeProvider.

Answer (score 3):

This seem to work for me

GlobalStyleOverrides.js

```
import { createTheme, responsiveFontSizes } from '@mui/material/styles';

export default function GlobalStyleOverrides() {
  const theme = createTheme({       
    typography: {
      fontFamily: [
        '"Bebas Neue"',
        'Roboto',
        '"Helvetica Neue"',
        'Arial',
        'sans-serif',
      ].join(','),         
      body1: {
        fontFamily: "'Poppins', Arial, sans-serif",
      },
    },
    components: {
      MuiButton: {
        variants: [
          {
            props: { variant: 'contained' },
            style: {
              textTransform: 'none',
              border: `10px dashed red`,
            },
          },              
        ],
      },
    },
  });

  return responsiveFontSizes(theme);
}
```

App.js

```
import GlobalStyleOverrides from 'components/_base/global-style-overrides/GlobalStyleOverrides';
...
function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={GlobalStyleOverrides()}>
      <Router>
        ...
      </Router>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When using an intermediate theme it is important to put the font there, for example:

```
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";

export const inter = Inter({
  subsets: ["latin"],
});

let theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    allVariants: {
      fontFamily: inter.style.fontFamily,
    },
  },
  breakpoints: {
    values: {
      xs: 0,
      sm: 656,
      md: 1023,
      lg: 1440,
      xl: 1920,
    },
  },
});

const Mytheme = createTheme(theme, {
  typography: {
    h1: {
      fontWeight: 700,
      [theme.breakpoints.between("xs", "md")]: {
        fontSize: "40px",
        lineHeight: "48px",
      },
      [theme.breakpoints.between("md", "xl")]: {
        fontSize: "56px",
        lineHeight: "64px",
      },
    },
    h2: {
      fontWeight: 700,
      fontSize: "40px",
      lineHeight: "48px",
    },
    h3: {
      fontWeight: 700,
      fontSize: "32px",
      lineHeight: "40px",
    },
  },
});

export default Mytheme;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

After **MUI 5**, the methods have been slightly changed.

For your usecase, good practice is create a global theme object and adjust it to your needs. Note that you can fine tune different Typography variants as well!

```js
import {createTheme} from "@mui/material/styles";

const theme = createTheme(
    {
        typography: {
            fontFamily: ['Merriweather', 'serif'].join(','),
            fontSize: 16,
            h2: {
                fontSize: "60px",
                fontWeight: "bold",
            }
        },
    }
)
```

And then wrap themeProvider arounf your app component:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import theme from "./theme";
import {ThemeProvider} from "@mui/material/styles";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);

root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <App/>
        </ThemeProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

**Important!**

While using [external fonts](https://fonts.google.com/), make sure if you import it as well.
For eg: in "index.html" add these lines -

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merriweather:wght@300;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```